# How to sort a file containing names with a script?

Tags: bash, shell

Assuming I have a file called "students" containing this:

```
NEWTON Isaac
MAXWELL James
EDISON Thomas
TESLA Nikola
```

how I am supposed to sort these names with a bash script in shell ?
Do I need to use a delimiter with carriage return ? Will this support accentuated characters ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: On SO we do encourage people to add their efforts in their post, kindly do so and let us know then.

Comment: sort based on first name or last name ? Please give details of the expected output

Comment: Unclear what your problem is. The `sort` command with no options should do exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the `sort` function.

```
$ cat stud.txt
NEWTON Isaac
MAXWELL James
EDISON Thomas
TESLA Nikola
$ sort stud.txt
EDISON Thomas
MAXWELL James
NEWTON Isaac
TESLA Nikola
```

To sort on last name, use the `-k` option.

```
$ sort -k 2 stud.txt
NEWTON Isaac
MAXWELL James
TESLA Nikola
EDISON Thomas
```